# Split a list into half by even and odd indexes? TailRecursive + match

Tags: list, scala

Define a  tail recursive function:`def divide[A](l: List[A]): (List[A], List[A])` that will split the list into two. In the first, there will be elements on even indexes, in the second, there will be elements on odd indexes.
for `List (1, 3, 5, 6, 7)`, the function should return: `(List (1, 5, 7), List (3, 6))`.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
object Main extends App {
  def divide[A](l: List[A]): (List[A], List[A]) = {
    @tailrec
    def helper(l1: List[A], l2: List[A]) = {
      ... match {
      case
```

Any help would be great, i dont even know how to start, because i cant simply use  x % 2 == 0 with case..

Comment: You can use `if` inside a case.

Comment: You can also use zipWithIndex

Comment: Your helper wants to have "what's left of the list" on it, and then what if on each iteration it attempts to put an element on each of l1 and l2?

Comment: Here is the template for your function, it should be pretty straightforward to finish it: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/s3bPbte5TWaV8hjR1yxItA/3

Comment: As with any recursion, think about the base case(s)...

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have, which is not a `tailrec`, but does not reverse the list, is:

```
def divide[A](l: List[A]): (List[A], List[A]) = {
  def helper(l: List[A]): (List[A], List[A]) = l match {
    case Nil => (Nil, Nil)
    case head :: Nil => (List(head), Nil)
    case even :: odd :: rest =>
      val (evenList, oddList) = helper(rest)
      (even :: evenList, odd :: oddList)
  }

  helper(l)
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vUZkkfuTQBWmv60UUVvrxA).

If you'd like to do that in the functional way, you can do:

```
val (evenWithIndex, oddWithIndex) = List(1, 3, 5, 6, 7).zipWithIndex.partition(_._2 % 2 == 0)
val even = evenWithIndex.map(_._1)
val odd = oddWithIndex.map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could think of the base case first - A list with one element. In that case, you need to put that in the list of odd indices.
If you have more elements, you need to call the same method, but for the second call, you need to put the element in the list of event indices.

Also, you may notice that, if you have an odd number of elements in the list, you have more numbers in the list of odd indices than that of the even. In case if you have an even number of elements, you have an equal number of elements in both lists.
So you may think of a function like below,

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def divide[A](l: List[A]): (List[A], List[A]) = {
    @tailrec
    def helper(l: List[A], list1:List[A], list2:List[A]):(List[A], List[A]) = {
        l match {
            case Nil if list1.size > list2.size => (list1.reverse, list2.reverse) // case 1: odd number of elements
            case Nil if list1.size < list2.size => (list2.reverse, list1.reverse) // case 2: odd number of elements
            case Nil if list1.size == list2.size => (list1.reverse, list2.reverse) // case 3: even number of elements
            case head::tail => helper(tail, list2, head::list1) 
        }
    }
    helper(l, List(), List())
}
```

Now if you see closely, case 1 never occurs as we are swapping the positions of the lists of the odd and even indices. So, we can remove this.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def divide[A](l: List[A]): (List[A], List[A]) = {
    @tailrec
    def helper(l: List[A], list1:List[A], list2:List[A]):(List[A], List[A]) = {
        l match {
            case Nil if list1.size < list2.size  => (list2.reverse, list1.reverse) // case 1: odd number of elements
            case Nil                             => (list1.reverse, list2.reverse) // case 2: even number of elements
            case head::tail                      => helper(tail, list2, head::list1) 
        }
    }
    helper(l, List(), List())
}
```

**Update**

Based on the comment by @Dima, I have removed the extra check from the second case. Also, the code based on the approach he mentioned is,

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def divide[A](l: List[A]): (List[A], List[A]) = {
    @tailrec
    def helper(l: List[A],
            i: Int,
            result:(List[A], List[A])):(List[A], List[A]) = l match {
        case Nil  => (result._1.reverse, result._2.reverse)
        case head::tail if i%2 == 0 => helper(tail, (i+1), (head::result._1, result._2))
        case head::tail => helper(tail, (i+1), (result._1, head::result._2)) 
    }
    helper(l, 0, (List(), List()))
}
```

Comment: Don't need the guard on the second `case Nil ..` clause. Also, perhaps, _too clever_ ... Why not just carry the counter?

Comment: Can be done without `if`, without `.size`, without comparisons. Just 3 `case` statements.

Comment: @Dima agreed, but instead of an extra counter, we may use the size of the list.

Comment: @SwapanPramanick Just because you _can_ do that, doesn't mean you _should_ :) "Extra counter" is free, size of the list is a linear operation ... There is no upside, and it makes the implementation quadratic. Also, what you did with the "update" is functionally wrong too: the order of the "odd and even" lists in the output depends on whether the list size of off or even to begin with.

Comment: @jwvh it can be done with just a `case Nil` and a `case head :: tail`...

Comment: @Dima Thanks for clarifying. Updated the answer.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Curious what you have in mind ... Like `Seq(head).take(i % 2)  ::: result._1` ?